# Fastapi automatically serialize ObjectId from mongodb

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, fastapi, pydantic

I'm using FastAPI with MongoDB. I want my backend to respond to a simple get at `domain/items/` with a list from the Mongodb database.

First, I extend the Mongodb `ObjectId` class to be converted to string by FastAPI, and define my `Item` model specifying in its config that `ObjectId` and `PyObjectId` types should be converted to string:

```py
class PyObjectId(ObjectId):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, v):
        if not ObjectId.is_valid(v):
            raise ValueError("Invalid objectid")
        return ObjectId(v)

    @classmethod
    def __modify_schema__(cls, field_schema):
        field_schema.update(type="string")



class Item(BaseModel):
    mongo_id: PyObjectId = Field(default_factory=PyObjectId, alias='_id')
    name: str

    class Config:
        allow_population_by_field_name = True
        json_encoders = {PyObjectId: str, ObjectId: str}
```

then, I define the `get` method specifying the returned model:

```py
@app.get("/items/", response_model=List[Item])
async def list_items(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 0):
    """List all items in the database"""
    items = await ITEMS.find(skip=skip, limit=limit).to_list(MAX_TO_LIST)
    return JSONResponse(status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK, content=items)
```

However, if I try to perform a GET request, an exception is raised from the line that returns the `JSONResponse`:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'ObjectId' is not JSON serializable
```

First of all, I do not understand what is the difference between the `json_encoders = {PyObjectId: str, ObjectId: str}` in the `Item` model config and the `field_schema.update(type="string")` in the `PyObjectId` `__modify_schema__()` method. Do we need both? And why?

Second, I do not understand why isn't the `ObjectId` field of each item transformed into string automatically. What am I missing or doing wrong?

NOTE: I know I could just iterate the `items` returned by Mongodb, transforming them to dict and trasnforming their `'_id'` field into a string, but I would like FastAPI and Pydantic to do this automatically.

Comment: Override the ```__str__``` method of PyObjectId

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything... although if in the get I do for item in items: item['_id'] = str(item['_id']) things work

Comment: The json_encoder is registered for `PyObjectId`, but it's complaining about not knowing how to serialize `ObjectId` - these are not the same classes

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this. First I declared this ObjectID class.

```
"""Defines the object id model/class."""
# ruff: noqa
from typing import Any

from bson import ObjectId
from pydantic.json_schema import JsonSchemaValue
from pydantic_core import core_schema


class ObjectIdPydanticAnnotation:
    """Defines a wrapper class around the mongodb ObjectID class adding serialization."""

    @classmethod
    def validate_object_id(cls, v: Any, handler) -> ObjectId:
        if isinstance(v, ObjectId):
            return v

        s = handler(v)
        if ObjectId.is_valid(s):
            return ObjectId(s)
        else:
            msg = "Invalid ObjectId"
            raise ValueError(msg)

    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_core_schema__(
        cls,
        source_type,
        _handler,
    ) -> core_schema.CoreSchema:
        assert source_type is ObjectId  # noqa: S101
        return core_schema.no_info_wrap_validator_function(
            cls.validate_object_id,
            core_schema.str_schema(),
            serialization=core_schema.to_string_ser_schema(),
        )

    @classmethod
    def __get_pydantic_json_schema__(cls, _core_schema, handler) -> JsonSchemaValue:
        return handler(core_schema.str_schema())
```

And then I use it like this:

```
"""Defines the models/classes for rooms."""
from typing import Annotated

from bson import ObjectId
from models.object_id import ObjectIdPydanticAnnotation
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class Item(BaseModel):
    """Defines the Room class according to the database schema."""

    id: Annotated[ObjectId, ObjectIdPydanticAnnotation] | None = Field(
        default=None,
        alias="_id",
    )
    name: str
```